# Create a tree data structure with the same shape as another

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion, tree

Let's say I have a typical tree data structure that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    att1: 'asdasd',
    att2: 42,
    att3: true,
    subs: [ ...other objects... ]
  },
  ...other objects...
]
```

It can have any shape and number of nodes, but every node has these three attributes (which have of course different values for each node).

Now, I'd like to create a new tree that would have the exact same hierarchy, but it should hold the data let's say in a format like this:

```
[
  {
    data: { att1: 'asdasd', att2: 42, att3: true },
    subs: [ ...other objects... ]
  },
  ...other objects...
]
```

*( One way of implementing this would be to write a recursive function that visits every node of the original tree, creates the `data` attribute for each one, fills up its content by the three attributes `att1`, `att2` and `att3`, then removes these attributes of the node. This way I would have this new tree. But I don't want to change the original tree, so this is not an option for me. I also don't want to clone the tree using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` or in some other way and then perform the same procedure described above for this new tree. )*

Instead, I'm looking for a method to generate this new tree node by node, as I'm reading the original tree node by node.

A method I can already write that visits every node of the original tree:

```
public copyTree(originalTree: Array<object>): Array<object> {

  const newTree: Array<object> = [];

  function f(subtree: Array<object>): void {
    for (const node of subtree) {

      // Missing here: Somehow add the current node to newTree

      if (node['subs'].length > 0) f(node['subs']);
    }
  }
  f(originalTree);
  return newTree;

}
```

How could I complete this method (or you can show me a different implementation too) to generate the new tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using the `Array.prototype.map` function and recursion:

```
public copyTree(originalTree: Array<object>): Array<object> {
  return originalTree.map(({ subs, ...data }: any) => ({
    data,
    subs: this.copyTree(subs)
  }));
}
```

Comment: I never have thought of using recursion this way inside a `map()`. I love this one probably the most.

Answer (score 2):

If you start by defining interfaces for your input and output shapes, you can use them and any resulting TypeScript errors to help guide you:

```
interface Attributes {
    att1: string;
    att2: number;
    att3: boolean;
}

type InputNode = Attributes & {
    subs: InputNode[];
}

interface OutputNode {
    data: Attributes;
    subs: OutputNode[];
}
```

Once we have those, we can set up our function definition as

```
function copyTree(originalTree: InputNode[]): OutputNode[] {
```

And then you can use rest/spread to help transfer everything around:

```
function copyTree(originalTree: InputNode[]): OutputNode[] {
    return originalTree.map(input => {
        const {
            subs,
            ...data
        } = input;

        return {
            subs: copyTree(subs),
            data,
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: I really like this approach with the type alias and interface definitions and then letting typescript do the work. For my current task I find it a bit overkill however, but this example gave me some new aspects to consider for my other works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd do it using `map` and the spread/rest operators:

```
const array = [...];

const copy = array.map(item => {
    const {att1, att2, att3, ...rest} = item;
    return { data: {att1, att2, att3}, ...rest };
});
```

In this function, `rest` will hold all the properties in the object except `att1`, `att2`, `att3`. When creating the new object, adding `...rest` adds the other properties to the resulting object, so, if you have:

```
{
    att1: '1',
    att2: '2',
    att3: '3',
    subs: [...],
    other: 'other'
}
```

you'd end with objects like this:

```
{
    data: {att1: '1', att2: '2', att3: '3'},
    subs: [...],
    other: 'other'
}
```

Comment: Can it be that this one only works for one dimensional arrays and not for a tree structure I have, or do I overlook something?